# First character got replace with the last character

Tags: python, email

Ok I am getting bit weird response

I am executing the below file over another file.

verify-email.sh ([source](https://github.com/socomm/verify-email))

```
import subprocess
import sys
import telnetlib

#print 'email:<%s> \n' % str(sys.argv[1])

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print "ERROR:\tYou must provide an email address you wish to validate."
    sys.exit(1)

rcpt = 'rcpt to:<%s>\n' % str(sys.argv[1])

print rcpt

domain = str(sys.argv[1]).split('@')[1]

print domain

server = (subprocess.check_output(['dig', '+short', domain,'MX'])).split('\n')
print 'Server:<%s>\n' % server

server.pop()
server.sort()

print 'Server[0]:<%s>\n' % server[0]
server = (server[0]).split(' ')[1].rsplit('.', 1)[0]

print 'Server after spliting:<%s>\n' % server

#============================[ TELNET SESSION ]=================================
telnet = telnetlib.Telnet(server, "25")
telnet.write('ehlo computer.com\n')
telnet.write('mail from:<otto@earth.org>\n')
telnet.write(rcpt)
telnet.write('quit\n')
#print 'rcpt final:<%s>\n' % rcpt

return_code = (telnet.read_all().split('\n')[-3]).split(' ')[0]
#print 'return_code:<%s>\n' % return_code

if return_code != '250':
    #print '%r is *NOT* a valid recipient on %s' % (str(sys.argv[1]), domain)
    sys.exit(2)
else:
    print str(sys.argv[1])
    sys.exit(0)
```

I have the file(sample.txt) that contains the list of email as:

```
carathas@aol.com
029@aol.com
08norcal2pl@aol.com
08norcascott@aol.com
08normanb@aol.com
0gt@aol.com
1-nov@aol.com
1.finofear534@aol.com
```

I am running Unix script that will process sample.txt line by line and run ./verify-email.sh over this.

```
while read in; 
    do 
      ./verify-email.py "$in"; 
    done < /home/itstym/Desktop/email_database/sample.txt
```

But I am getting the echo (line 7)

```
>cpt to:<carathas@aol.com
instead of this
rcpt to:<carathas@aol.com
```

Comment: Because your input file has Windows line endings, and `\r` at end of lines are taken to be part of the addresses.  On a side note: (1) many hosts don't return anything useful for `VRFY`, and (2) there are dedicated spam tools that can do that better.

Comment: IMHO its a little misleading that a python script has a `.sh` extension.

Comment: @SatōKatsura can you tell me any free tool apart from this?